# Configuring two jobs in Spring Batch leads to not finished step(stays on status STARTED) but the job shows that is finished

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, java-17

I have Spring batch project which initially i have one Job configured called firstJob here is the code:

This is the parent classes which are extended by the job(s)(worker and manager):

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchIntegration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class ManagerBaseJobConfiguration {

    private final JobRepository jobRepository;
    private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
    private final RemotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory managerStepBuilderFactory;
    private final ApplicationProperties appProperties;
    private final DirectChannel requests;
    private final DirectChannel replies;

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public IdBoundaryPartitioner idBoundaryPartitioner(
            DataSource source,
            @Value("#{jobParameters['" + IfrsJob.CLIENT_PARAM_NAME + "']}") String client,
            @Value("#{jobParameters['" + IfrsJob.OBJECT_ID_PARAM_NAME + "']}") String objectId,
            @Value("#{stepExecution}") StepExecution stepExecution
    ) {
        return new IdBoundaryPartitioner(source, client, objectId, stepExecution.getJobExecutionId());
    }

    @Bean
    public Step deleteTable() {
        return new StepBuilder("deleteDataTasklet", jobRepository).tasklet(deleteDataTasklet, transactionManager).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step instDataLoaderStep() {
        return new StepBuilder("instDataLoader", jobRepository).tasklet(instDataLoader, transactionManager).build();
    }

}
```

Nothing special the IdBoundaryPartitioner method itself its just creating partitioners:

```
 try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(PARTITION_STATEMENT);
        ) {
            stmt.setInt(1, gridSize);
            stmt.setString(2, client);
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    partitions.put(
                            PARTITION_PREFIX + (partitions.keySet().size() + 1),
                            createExecutionContextForPartition(rs.getString("idextern_start"), rs.getString("idextern_end"))
                    );
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Exception occurs ",e);
        }


    private ExecutionContext createExecutionContextForPartition(String idexternStart, String idexternEnd) {
        ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
        executionContext.putString(FIRST_IDEXTERN_KEY, idexternStart);
        executionContext.putString(LAST_IDEXTERN_KEY, idexternEnd);
        executionContext.putString(CLIENT_KEY, client);
        executionContext.putString(MANAGER_JOB_ID, String.valueOf(managerJobId));
        return executionContext;
    }
```

Also for the worker :

```
@Profile("worker")
@EnableBatchIntegration
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class WorkerBaseJobConfiguration {

    private final JobRepository jobRepository;
    private final JobCache<I9Data[]> cache;
    private final ApplicationProperties appProperties;
    private final InstDataLoader instDataLoader;
    private final ContractLoader contractLoader;
    private final CacheItemWriter cacheItemWriter;
    private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
    private final InstDataJpaCache instDataJpaCache;
    private final AddAccountProcessor addAccountProcessor;
    private final RemotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory workerStepBuilderFactory;
    private final CacheJobListener<I9Data[]> jobListener;
    private final WorkerJobListener workerJobListener;

    private static final boolean CUSTOMER_USES_BB = true;

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public CacheItemReader cacheItemReader() {
        return new CacheItemReader(cache);
    }

    @Bean
    public Step contractLoaderTaskletStep() {
        return new StepBuilder("contractLoaderTaskletStep", jobRepository).tasklet(contractLoader, transactionManager).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step instDataLoaderStep() {
        return new StepBuilder("instDataLoader", jobRepository).tasklet(instDataLoader, transactionManager).build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Step calculateStep() {
        return new StepBuilder("calculateStep", jobRepository).<I9Data, I9Data>chunk(
                appProperties.getJobParameters().getChunkSize(),
                transactionManager
        )
                .reader(cacheItemReader())
                // pass null, the really used argument will be received from the job
                // parameters
                // see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-partitioner
                .processor(dataProcessor(null, null))
                .writer(cacheItemWriter)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public DataProcessor dataProcessor(
            @Value("#{jobParameters['" + IfrsJob.JOB_TIME_PARAM_NAME + "']}") Long jobTimeStamp,
            @Value("#{jobParameters['" + IfrsJob.DECISION_DATE_PARAM_NAME + "']}") Date decisionDate
    ) {
        LocalDateTime calculationRunStart = Instant.ofEpochMilli(jobTimeStamp).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
        LocalDate decisionDateLocal = decisionDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        DataStepProcessor i9CleanUp = new DataStepProcessor(instDataJpaCache, calculationRunStart, CUSTOMER_USES_BB);
        RiskProvProcessor<I9Data> riskProvProcessor = new RiskProvProcessor<>(
                decisionDateLocal,
                instDataJpaCache.getInstDataJA(),
                instDataJpaCache.getInstDatRecht()
        );
        EndOfContractProcessor<Data> endOfContractProcessor = new EndOfContractProcessor<>(decisionDateLocal);
        EadProcessor<Data> eadProcessor = new EadProcessor<>(
                instDataJpaCache.getOcCalculationContext().getDecisionDate(),
                instDataJpaCache.getInstDataJA()
        );
        return new DataProcessor(
                List.of(i9CleanUp, addAccountProcessor, eadProcessor, endOfContractProcessor, riskProvProcessor),
                instDataJpaCache
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJobParametersExtractor remoteJobParametersExtractor() {
        DefaultJobParametersExtractor extractor = new DefaultJobParametersExtractor();
        extractor.setKeys(
                new String[] {
                        IdBoundaryPartitioner.FIRST_IDEXTERN_KEY,
                        IdBoundaryPartitioner.LAST_IDEXTERN_KEY,
                        IdBoundaryPartitioner.MANAGER_JOB_ID }
        );
        return extractor;
    }
}
```

This is the first job created initially have manager and worker class;

```
@Configuration
@Profile("manager")
public class JobManagerPartitionConfiguration extends ManagerBaseJobConfiguration {
@Bean
    public Step firstJobManagerStep() {
        return getManagerStepBuilderFactory().get("firstJobManagerStep")
                .partitioner(
                        "remotefirstJobAsStep",
                        // will be injected by Spring via @StepScope
                        idBoundaryPartitioner(null, null, null, null)
                )
                .gridSize(getAppProperties().getJobParameters().getGridSize())
                .outputChannel(getRequests())
                .inputChannel(getReplies())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job firstJob(Step firstJobManagerStep) {
        return new JobBuilder("firstJob", getJobRepository()).incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(firstJobManagerStep)
                .build();
    }
}
```

and worker:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("worker")
public class JobWorkerPartitionConfiguration extends WorkerBaseJobConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    Job remoteFirstJob() {
        return new JobBuilder("remoteFirstJob", getJobRepository()).start(instDataLoaderStep())
                .next(contractLoaderTaskletStep())
                .next(calculateStep())
                .listener(getJobListener())
                .listener(getWorkerJobListener())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step remoteFirstJobAsStep(DirectChannel requests, DirectChannel replies) {
        return getWorkerStepBuilderFactory().get("remoteFirstJobAsStep")
                .inputChannel(requests)
                .outputChannel(replies)
                .job(remoteFirstJob())
                .parametersExtractor(remoteJobParametersExtractor())
                .listener(new StepExecutionLogListener())
                .build();
    }
}
```

And this is working as expected, in the databse it is shown that every of the steps is COMPLETED.

But the thing is that when i add another job which extended these classes(SecondJobManager and SecondJobWorker) and it is absolutely the same logic as the other job but with different name: "secondJob" and when this happens, something its conflicting each other because when i start the firstJob the  "firstJobManagerStep" it is in not completed its stays on "STARTED" status and the job it is shown that is completed. I've tried a lot of things to fix this issue but nothing helps. Maybe some timeout, or thread conflicting each other but no success for now. Any ideas?

Interesting things which i try:

- Starting first the secondJob, then the firstJob and both are completed sometimes.
- Started several times firstJob and in the 4th or 5th try even the job it is not started.
- Started first the firstJob and it fails the step - firstMangerStep
- Started the secondJob and the job is successfully done.

I expect the two jobs finished their steps.

Comment: If you are extending the same classes you will endup with duplicate beans or overridden beans with the wrong content.

Comment: No that will not happen, even if i create it in one class everything will lead to this problem again. Also the beans are created once with their unique names i am just using them in the other classes.

Comment: Are the requests/replies channels shared between jobs? Have you tried to configure a separate request/reply channel per job?

Comment: Yes also, tried to create separate replies and request channels for both jobs, but that also didn't work.